# Can Cassandra c# mapper map blob to object?

Tags: cassandra

I'm using Cassandra C# driver (v3) and have a need to map an object into blob data type (I may change its structure in the future).

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The C# data type that corresponds to the C* blob is byte[]. If I have a C* table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE datatable (
  id INT,
  segment INT,
  data BLOB,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, segment)
)
```

I create a corresponding C# class:

```
[TableAttribute("datatable")]
public class DataTableRecord {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int segment { get; set; }
    public byte[] data { get; set; }
}
```

I insert to it like this:

```
DataTableRecord record = new DataTableRecord {
  id = 1,
  segment = 1,
  data = /* your blob data */
};

Mapper mapper = new Mapper(session);
mapper.Insert<DataTableRecord>(record);
```

Works great. Remember blobs are limited to 16 Meg.